# C:Finding longest length of same character in a 2-D character array

Tags: c

Can someone please help me giving an algorithm or a pseudo code for the following C program?

There is an n*m grid consisting of lower case characters of the English Alphabet.
You need to determine the maximum number of occurrences of a character contiguously either vertically or horizontally.

Input
Input description.

The first line of the input contains T test-cases.The first line of each Test Case contains n(No. of Rows), m(No. of Columns). Each of the next n lines contain m characters each denoting the grid.

Input
In each case output the answer as the problem statement specified

```
2
3 3
aaa
abc
dca
2 3
fgh
frq
```

Output:

```
3
2
```

Comment: Sounds like a programming challenge. The point of these is for you to figure it out yourself.

Comment: You should at least try to write a basic algorithm from your own before we help you.

Comment: I didnt mean to ask for the entire code. Just wanted a brief way of approach to the solution.

Comment: I did write the entire program. But I am unable to get the exact logic.

Comment: You should take one problem after another, and not try to do all in one go. For example, let's say you already have an array[n][m] filled.
What algorithm can you do in order to know the longest sequence ?
After you have resolved that, you can try to fill the array from your input.

Comment: The algorithm is similar to most "find max" problems. Keep 2 variables, one with the candidate value and another with the quantity. In your loop, check the length of the current sequence, if it's bigger than the max quantity, replace the value and quantity with the current value and length.

Comment: You just need 2 2-dimensional loops: one that goes by row and tests the length of horizontal sequences, and another that goes by columns and checks the length of vertical sequences.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a brief overview. I will try the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to give the program a character and a 2D array of characters and it returns the largest number of occurrences in a row?

I would go with something simple along the lines of

```
func(char** grid, xlength, ylengh, char k){
    int i;
    int j;
    int number = 0;
    int max = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < xlength; i++){
        for(j = 1; j < ylength; j<<){
            if(grid[i][j-1] == grid[i][j])
               number++;

            if(number > max) 
               max = number;

            if(grid[i][j-1] != grid[i][j]number) = 0;
            }
        }
    return max;
}
```

You would have to do the same thing twice, where you switch the rows an columns. But this should work.